# Continuous function $f(\vartheta A)$ where $A$ is an Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

Consider the matrices $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}$ defined as:

$A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right), A_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{array}\right), A_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right) .$

If a matrix $A$ is defined by
$A=n_{1} A_{1}+n_{2} A_{2}+n_{3} A_{3}$ where $n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}$ are real constants satisfying $n_{1}^{2}+n_{2}^{2}+n_{3}^{2}=1$

> **(a)** Show that $A$ is an [*Hermitian matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).

> **(b)** Find the eigenvalues of the eigenvalue equation $A|\lambda\rangle=\lambda|\lambda\rangle .$ If we denote $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ be normalized eigenvectors, find $|+\rangle\langle+|$ and $|-\rangle\langle-|$ from the Spectral theorem.

> **(c)** Show that

> $f(\vartheta A)=\frac{f(\vartheta)+f(-\vartheta)}{2} I+\frac{f(\vartheta)-f(-\vartheta)}{2} A$

> where $I=\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ and $f(x)$
> is a continuous function.

Comment: Please, don't put a link to the question itself. It's better if you write the whole question in the body of your post, and put a more detailed title.

Comment: What do you mean with "|-><-|" and "|+><+|". Please, use MathJax in your body. You can read about it in the link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: See [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Normalized+eigenvector).

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso, see the answer for the notation explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: the question makes use of the [Dirac bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). widely used (and very convenient) in quantum mechanics (but it is not strictly needed here and not much used by mathematicians, so I will try to avoid it).*

a) The matrix $A$ is hermitian because it is a linear combination ***(with real coefficients)*** of hermitian matrices.

b)  You did it, but let me state (for clarity) that this question uses the Dirac bra-ket notation: formally the normalized eigenvectors satisfy $ A |+\rangle\ =  |+\rangle\ $ and $ A |-\rangle\ = - |-\rangle\ $. According to this notation, the operators $P_-=|-\rangle\langle-|$ and $P_+=|+\rangle\langle+|$ are the projectors along the two eigenvectors. The identity can be expressed as $\mathbb{1} = P_+ + P_-$.

c)  Suppose you can expand $f$ as a power series (otherwise the question makes little sense),
$$
f(x) = \sum_m a_m x^m
$$
Therefore, using $A= P_+ - P_-$ and $P_-^m = P_-$ (and the same for $P_+$), you have
$$
f(t A) = \sum_m a_m t^m A^m = \sum_m a_m t^m [P_{+}^m -mP_{+}^{m-1} P_{-}^m+... + (-P_{-})^m]
$$
However, $P_- P_+ = 0 $ because they project on orthogonal subspaces, so that
$$
f(t A) = \sum_m a_m t^m A^m = \sum_m a_m t^m (P_{+}^m +(-P_{-})^m)
= \sum_m a_m t^m [ P_{+} + (-1)^m P_{-} ]
\\ =  \sum_m a_m t^m  P_{+}   + \sum_m a_m  (-t)^m P_{-} = f(t) P_+ + f(-t) P_- 
$$
Using $A= P_+ - P_-$ and $\mathbb{1} = P_+ + P_-$ you have the thesis.

Comment: It is completely sensible to define $f(A)$ for a continuous function $f$ and a Hermitian matrix $A$. In this setting, it suffices to define $f$ on real diagonal matrices and generalize appropriately via unitary similarity.  We indeed conclude that
$$
f(\theta (P_+ - P_-)) = f(\theta)P_+ + f(-\theta)P_-.
$$
In a more general setting, we might appeal to the [Borel functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus).

Comment: That's true, I was sloppy in writing "it makes little sense". I wanted to show explicitly how to obtain the result just by using the natural operation of matrix multiplication (otherwise the answer would just be "it's because of the Borel calculus").

Comment: I think that arguing via diagonalization gives a natural enough justification (but I agree that using the Taylor series is more intuitive)